# Proving that a formula defines an explicit bijection $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm wondering if the following argument is sufficient to prove that the below map of sets defines a bijection.

> Define $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(a,b) = 2^a \cdot (2b - 1)$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written uniquely, up to ordering of factors, as a product of primes. Namely, $n = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n p_i^{e_i}$. If $p_j = 2$ for some $j$, then we take $a = e_j$; otherwise, $a = 0$. Then the product of the remaining primes is odd, and hence is equal to $2b - 1$ for some $b \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $f(a,b) = n$. Since this factorization into primes is unique, $f$ is injective.

Is this sufficient?

Comment: By definition, bijections not only inject, but also surject. Do you take $0\in\Bbb N$? If so, $f$ doesn't surject; if not, it still doesn't, but $2^{a-1}(2b-1)$ does. You probably want to either take the latter approach or else use the existence of injections in both directions to prove a bijection exists with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Comment: Reading that, I got confused as to whether you were trying to show $f(a,b)$ was injective or  $f^{-1}(n)$ is injective.  It is also not clear whether you think $0\in \mathbb N$ or not

Comment: @J.G. - same timestamp and essentially similar  points

Comment: These are very good points. I do want to include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, so I've modified the map, though I think $2^a \cdot (2b - 1)$ is what I had in mind. Does this work?

Comment: You're mixing and matching here. Let $\Bbb N_0$ denote the version with $0$; let $\Bbb N_+$ denote the version without. The function $2^a(2b-1)$ bijects $\Bbb N_0\times\Bbb N_+$ with $\Bbb N_+$. If you want to biject $\Bbb N_0^2$ with $\Bbb N_0$, try $2^a(2b+1)-1$. However, bijecting $\Bbb N_+^2$ with $\Bbb N_+$ using $2^{a-1}(2b-1)$ is an arguably less messy restatement of the same idea.